# how-to bann/block spam php scripts?

Tags: linux, debian, email-spam, spam-prevention

I could detect some PHP-scripts which are sending spam emails. Is there a way to bann or block files like this?

Do I have to delete those files or does "chmod 0 spam.php" help to stop sending spam emails?

I can't find a solution via Google. I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Doesn't that imply your server's been hacked and being abused? If so, you want to KEEP those scripts? You should be figuring out how those scripts got installed in the first place.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? You have a PHP script called "spam.php" which spammers are using? Then why is it there in the first place?

Comment: spam.php was just an example. The name is variable. For example: blog.php, admin.php, sql.php and some other namings. I think any or some customers have a bug or gap in security within their CMS like typo3 or webedition. The server packages are up to date.

Comment: If your site runs scripts which were put there by an intruder, just disabling ir removing them won't do much good in the long run. You need to make sure the security hole they used to get in gets plugged, then restore from a known-clean backup, or from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about clients with CMS, I'm assuming your server is used for shared hosting.
Take a look at [Config Server Firewall](http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html) the following features might be useful for you:

1. Alert when end-user scripts sending excessive emails per hour - for identifying spamming scripts
2. Suspicious process reporting - reports potential exploits running on the server
3. Directory and file watching - reports if a watched directory or a file changes

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! This is, what I've searched for! :) The software also looks nice.